# wchar_t reading

Tags: c, linked-list, wchar

I have a mistake in the function for reading the file but I don't know what is wrong. all the symbols are read correctly when the symbol is beyond the ASCII table.

```
while ((c = fgetwc(file)) != WEOF) {
        if (c != L'\n') {
            if (i == buf_length) {
                buf_length += BUF;
                wchar_t *rebuf = realloc(tmp, buf_length * sizeof(wchar_t));
                if (rebuf == NULL) {
                    free(tmp);
                    tmp = NULL;
                    buf_length = 0;
                    return EALLOC;
                } else {
                    tmp = rebuf;
                }
            }
            tmp[i] = (wchar_t)c;
            i++;
        } else {
            list->size++;
            tmp[i] = L'\0';
            insertLast(list, tmp);
            i = 0;
        }
```

Comment: I think your file might not be saved in unicode encoding

Comment: The problem is that when it reads some sybmols such like this ďšě that's not saving in linked list :(

Comment: When it read the symbol "ď" by this function it has code 196, but it isn't true it have to be u010F

Comment: fgetwc() doesn't do what you think it does.  It only reads wide characters when the file was opened in binary mode.  In text mode it still falls back to 8-bit encoding.  You need to document the compiler you use.  There are non-standard extensions to deal with Unicode encoded text files.

Comment: You have an off-by-one error by not considering space for the wide null string terminator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is _UNICODE defined?  Also, check that you do not get an error (use ferror and feof) when you encounter WEOF as it could mean either.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7sskzc1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx