# Read wide char from a stream created with fmemopen

Tags: c, unicode, stream, segmentation-fault, widechar

I'm trying to read a wide char from a stream that was created using `fmemopen` with a `char *`.

```
char *s = "foo bar foo";
FILE *f = fmemopen(s,strlen(s),"r");

wchar_t c = getwc(f);
```

`getwc` throws a segmentation fault, I checked using GDB.

I know this is due to opening the stream with [`fmemopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html), because calling `getwc` on a stream opened normally works fine.

Is there a wide char version of `fmemopen`, or is there some other way to fix this problem?

Comment: Please post a proper MCVE, the `fmemopen` invocation is invalid

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Oh, whoops, I missed that part. Sorry.

Comment: @MDXF: From the examples one might get the impression that perhaps [`iconv_open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/iconv_open.3.html) and [`iconv()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/iconv.3.html) might be a better solution to the underlying problem.

Comment: @MDXF: In fact, at least GNU libc uses `iconv` in the background - it uses a separate buffer for already-converted data. After you have set the locale (all, or `LC_CTYPE`), you can use [`nl_langinfo(CODESET)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nl_langinfo.3.html) to obtain the character set in a form you can supply to `iconv_open()`. While this is not ISO C, it is POSIX.1, and should be quite portable. (Since there is even GNU `libiconv`, this approach should be relatively easy to port across to any system using standard C, including Windows.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second line should read `FILE *f = fmemopen(s, strlen(s), "r");`. As posted, `fmemopen` has undefined behavior and might return `NULL`, which causes `getwc()` to crash.

Changing the `fmemopen()` line and adding a check for `NULL` fixes the crash but does not meet the OPs goal.

It seems wide orientation is not supported on streams open with `fmemopen()`, At least for the GNU C library.  Note that `fmemopen` is not defined in the C Standard but in POSIX.1-2008 and is not available on many systems (like OS/X).

Here is a corrected and extended version of your program:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *s = "foo bar foo";
    FILE *f = fmemopen((void *)s, strlen(s), "r");
    wchar_t c;

    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("fmemopen failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    printf("default wide orientation: %d\n", fwide(f, 0));
    printf("selected wide orientation: %d\n", fwide(f, 1));
    while ((c = getwc(f)) != WEOF) {
        printf("read %lc (%d 0x%x)\n", c, c, c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Run on linux:

```
default wide orientation: -1
selected wide orientation: -1
```

No output, `WEOF` is returned immediately.

Explanation for `fwide(f, 0)` from the linux man page:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> #include <wchar.h>
> int fwide(FILE *stream, int mode);
> ```
>
> When `mode` is zero, the `fwide()` function determines the current orientation of `stream`.  It returns a positive value if `stream` is  wide-character  oriented, that is, if wide-character I/O is permitted but char I/O is disallowed.  It returns a negative value if `stream` is byte oriented, i.e.,  if  char  I/O is permitted but wide-character I/O is disallowed. It returns zero if `stream` has no orientation yet; in this case the next I/O operation might change the orientation (to byte oriented if it is a char I/O operation, or to wide-character oriented if it is a wide-character I/O operation).
>
> Once a stream has an orientation, it cannot be changed and persists until the stream is closed.
>
> When `mode` is nonzero, the `fwide()` function first attempts to set `stream`'s orientation (to wide-character oriented if mode is greater than 0, or to byte oriented if `mode`  is less than 0).  It then returns a value denoting the current orientation, as above.

The stream returned by `fmemopen()` is byte-oriented and cannot be changed to wide-character oriented.

Comment: So there's no way to `fmemopen` a string and read wide characters from it?

Comment: @MDXF: Indeed I'm afraid the Glibc implementation does not support wide orientation.

Comment: `fwide` does not changes the orientation if the orientation is already defined. So the second call `fwide` has zero effect. You can try open stream this way `fmemopen(s, strlen(s), "r,ccs=UNICODE");`

Comment: @VadimHryshkevich: The first call to `fwide()` is a query for the current orientation. It returns byte-oriented. The second call attempts to change the orientation to wide and indeed fails. Your proposed approach is interesting. It is non standard but classic on some systems.

Comment: @chqrlie: This is from `fwide()` man page: "Once a stream has an orientation, it cannot be changed and persists until the stream is closed."   So the second call to `fwide()` has zero effect. 
P.S. 
1. I have looked into the source code of `fwide()` on my linux distrib: if the stream has not zero orientation `fwide()` just exits. 
2. From the source code of `fmemopen()`: there is no chance to change orientation of the stream in this function in any way.
3. It is possible to use function `freopen(NULL,"r",fmemopen(...))` to get stream without orientation, but I have tried this without luck.

Comment: @vadim_hr: yes, I already quoted the man page in the answer (just added more paragraphs for clarity) and got to the same conclusion: *The stream returned by `fmemopen()` is byte-oriented and cannot be changed to wide-character oriented.*  It is a pity that a stream orientation cannot be changed once set and that it is not handled generically enough to work for memory streams transparently.

Answer (score 3):

1. <del>Your second line does not use the correct number of parameters, does it?</del> corrected

   `FILE *fmemopen(void *buf, size_t size, const char *mode);`
2. glibc's `fmemopen` does not <del>(fully)</del> support wide characters AFAIK. There's also `open_wmemstream()`, which supports wide characters but is just for writing.
3. Is `_UNICODE` defined? See [wchar_t reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552296/wchar-t-reading).
   **Also**, have you set the locale to an encoding that supports Unicode, for example,  `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");`? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455658/does-wide-character-input-output-in-c-always-read-from-write-to-the-correct-s).
4. Consider using a temporary [file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737906/how-to-read-write-utf8-text-files-in-c). Consider using [fgetwc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7sskzc1(v=vs.71).aspx) / [4](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/fgetwc/) instead.

I have changed my code and adopted the code from @chqrlie  since it more close to the OP code but added the locale, otherwise it fails to produce correct output for extended/Unicode characters.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
    const char *s = "foo $€ bar foo";
    FILE *f = fmemopen((void *)s, strlen(s), "r");
    wchar_t c;

    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("fmemopen failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    printf("default wide orientation: %d\n", fwide(f, 0));
    printf("selected wide orientation: %d\n", fwide(f, 1));
    while ((c = getwc(f)) != WEOF) {
        printf("read %lc (%d 0x%x)\n", c, c, c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use `getwc()` only on unoriented or wide-oriented stream. From `getwc()` [man page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/getwc/): *The stream shall not have an orientation yet, or be wide-oriented.*
2. It is not possible to change stream orientation, if the stream already has orientation. From `fwide()` [man page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/fwide/): *Calling this function on a stream that already has an orientation cannot change it.*
3. Stream opened with glibc's `fmemopen()` has an byte-orientation and therefore can't be wide-oriented in any way. As described [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/uclibc/Glibc_vs_uClibc_Differences.txt) [uClibc](https://www.uclibc.org/about.html) has `fmemopen()` routine without this limitation.

Conclusion: You need to use [uClibc](https://www.uclibc.org/about.html) or another library or make your own `fmemopen()`.